# Is there a way to create new desktop spaces from keyboard only?

Tags: keyboard, spaces, desktop

We all know there is a way to to switch between desktops using keyboard shortcuts, 
but can we create new ones using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with some AppleScript. This will create a new desktop every time you run it:

```
tell application "System Events"
    do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control"
    tell process "Dock"
        set countDesktops to count buttons of list 1 of group 1
        --new desktop
        click button 1 of group 1
        --switch to new desktop
        repeat until (count buttons of list 1 of group 1) = (countDesktops + 1)
        end repeat
        click button (countDesktops + 1) of list 1 of group 1
    end tell
end tell
```

You can save this as a Universal Service you can assign a globally-available shortcut key combination to call it.

[Credit where credit is due](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176079/259811).

Comment: Something that easy is not fair ;-)

Comment: @klanomath you got an upvote from me for even attempting to do it without touching AppleScript! :D

Comment: ;-) I upvoted you also, presenting a really clean and easy Apple Script answer

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a new desktop space with the keyboard, but it's **really** cumbersome:

- enable Mouse Key toggle (5 times <kbd>alt</kbd>) in System Preferences > Accesibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Options > enable "Press the Option key..."
- hit <kbd>F3</kbd>
- hit <kbd>alt</kbd> 5 times
- move the cursor with the [respective keys](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18381?viewlocale=en_US) and navigate near the right upper corner
- hit either <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>5</kbd> (depending on your keyboard)
- hit <kbd>alt</kbd> 5 times
- hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and switch to the new space "[with a keyboard shortcut](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/06/switch-between-desktops-spaces-faster-in-os-x-with-control-keys/)".

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't a way to create a new space with only the keyboard. You'd still need to use the mouse/trackpad to drag a window to the (+) desktop thumbnail in the top-right corner (or just click on it) to create a new space.